# select and input inline alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling to align `select` and `input` element inline, but i'm unable to do so no matter what I do. I tried to use solutions from many stackoverflow questions but I'm not successfull. I'm sure its some dumb tiny mistake i'm overseeing. Please help, thanks in advance

http://plnkr.co/edit/23LX0GqcJzgkvM3j9jdx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using Bootstrap, I'd suggest using that to make your two columns:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <span class="form-group">
         <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value="">1</option>
          <option value="">2</option>
          <option value="">3</option>
          <option value="">4</option>
        </select>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <span class="form-group">
        <input id="title" ng-model="bug.title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Bug title" class="form-control" tabindex="1" required autofocus>  
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```